# Is it possible to pass something from the stack by reference?

Tags: reference, stack, computer-science, pass-by-reference

I came across something strange the other day in php, but this question is more general than that.

What I wonder is, is it possible to have a function that returns something which as far as I know means that the return value/function is on the stack and pass the result to a function which takes a reference?

With my limited knowledge I would say no, but thats just a feeling that I have, and I've learned to never trust my feelings when it comes to programming.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Why is the stack relevant?  You appear to be talking about first-class functions, which many languages do have, but PHP does not, at least not [without some help](https://gist.github.com/745878).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll try to rephrase my question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with references in PHP, but you can do this in C/C++ and some cases in C#.

The thing is that you have to be careful. A value on the stack is only valid as long as the function whos stack frame it belongs to hasn't returned (ignoring stuff like the red zone). C and C++ expect you to be smart enough to not use a dangling reference like this.

Anyway, it doesn't matter in PHP because it's a high level language and hides details of allocation like that from you. Most likely, all your objects are allocated on the heap.